# How to set media rate calculations for shipping?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I am incorporating UberCart into our existing Drupal 7 website. So far I am happy but can't seem to figure out how to set media rate calculations for shipping for publications and regular shipping quotes for everything else. Any guidance is appreciated.

Drupal 7.50 UberCart 3.6